# Koshas are both Brahman and Maya?

Tags: upanishads

In chapter 3 of the Taittiriya Upanishad, the koshas are said to be Brahman. But aren't the koshas also Maya, given their suffixes (eg "manomaya")?
Also, aren't the koshas anatman?

Comment: voting to close as your question is not clear. your question is not clear. Which Chapter 3? There are 3 books to the Taittiriya and 3 Chapter threes. Also, which verses are you asking about?

Comment: My translation has only one chapter 3.  Verses 2-6, which say that each sheath is Brahman. The question is, why are the sheaths both Maya and Brahman? Thanks.

Comment: It appears you are confused by the English spelling of Māyā (माया) and the mayaṭ suffix (मयट् प्रत्यय) of Sanskrit due to both being written the same without the diacritical marks.

Comment: Do they mean different things? And if so, what's the difference? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, they are different. Māyā (माया) has been used in many different contexts in Vedic literature, but primarily it means the divine power of creation of the divine being. The mayaṭ suffix (मयट् प्रत्यय) of Sanskrit is equivalent to the English suffix "-ful". So "manomaya" means "mindful" or "made of the mind". "Anandamaya" means "blissful" or "made of bliss".